# Expresión regular en JavaScript no me está respetando la longitud del "com"

Tags: javascript, regex

Lo que pasa, es que no me está respetando la longitud del "com" en la siguiente url: "https://dominio.com"

Si pongo "https://dominio.comm" me da `true`, cuando debería darme `false`, porque estoy superando la longitud establecida en la expresión regular.

Pero en cambio, si me funciona bien con la siguiente url: "https://www.dominio.com", si me respeta la longitud establecida del "com".

CODIGO:

```js
var str = "https://dominio.comm";
var patt1 = /^(https?\:\/\/)([a-z0-9-]+\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z]{2,3})?$/;
console.log(patt1.test(str)); // deberia darme false, y me da true
```

Comment: No se explicarte con exactitud el porque pero si eliminas la expresion `([a-z0-9-]+\.)?` te funcionara. Investigare el porque ya que ahora mismo no lo entiendo.

Comment: y so es `.gov` `.edu`.`.io` como vas a hacer?

Comment: Además, ¿para qué tantos paréntesis?!! ¿Y si la URL tuviese otro caracter que no esté entre a y z? ¿Y si el TLD tiene más de 3 caracteres? ¿Qué sentido tiene validar de esta forma? ¿Para qué? ¿Y si tiene una ruta además del dominio? ¿Podrías agregar ejemplos que deberían coincidir y ejemplos que no? Por favor, completa los puntos que se piden en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 0):

> /^(https?://)([a-z0-9-]+.)?([a-z0-9-]+)(.[a-z]{2,3})**?**$/

Es decir, el último bloque es opcional. Así que el `.comm` puede ser parseado por el bloque anterior `([a-z0-9-]+)` que no tiene restricción de longitud...

Compara [el regexp original](https://regex101.com/r/P1QWQc/1) con [el mismo sin el último grupo](https://regex101.com/r/p54s9e/1). Funcionan igual!

Solución: No hagas el último grupo opcional.

Como nota aparte, recordar que desde la liberalización de los TLDs es posible encontrar TLD con más de tres caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el último `?`. Este caracter especial indica que el token previo es opcional

A continuación he quitado el último `?`

```js
var str = "https://dominio.comm";
var patt1 = /^(https?\:\/\/)([a-z0-9-]+\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/;
console.log(patt1.test(str));
```

Nótese que ahora el resultado es `true`